# IndexOutOfBoundsException when binding children

Tags: grails, data-binding, grails-orm

I have the following gsp in Grails `2.1.1` (simplified version):

```
<g:form ...>
    <g:each in="${team.players}" var="player" status="i">
        <g:hiddenField name="players[${i}].id" value="${player.id}" />
        <g:textField name="players[${i}].name" value="${player.name}" />
        <g:textField name="players[${i}].position" value="${player.position}" />
    </g:each>
</g:form>
```

Given that the particular `Team` has 2 `players`, when I do the following in the controller I get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1`:

```
def teamInstance = Team.get(params.id)
teamInstance.properties = params // this is where IndexOutOfBoundsException happens
teamInstance.save()
```

Interestingly, when I remove `players[${i}].id` parameter the error goes away, but then the data for the two `players` is randomly swapped around because Grails doesn't know how to match the a player from the form to one in the `players` collection.

Anyone know what is going on here?

EDIT: Here is a sample app: https://github.com/zoran119/binding-test

Comment: Echoing the comment below, code for `Team` and `Player` would help. Your snippets work fine for me in 2.1.2 with a normal `belongsTo`/`hasMany` relationship between `Team` and `Players`, and `players` defined as a `List` in the `Team` domain class.

Comment: Sample app: https://github.com/zoran119/binding-test

Comment: Thanks for the sample app. I would suggest defining players as a List in your Team domain class.  To do this, just add the line: `List players` (without changing your `belongsTo`)  This should allow you to use index references (`[${i}]`) during binding.  More detail here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#sets,ListsAndMaps

Comment: `List players` adds an `index` column to the database table... cannot have that :(

Comment: Without the `List` definition, GORM uses a `Set` by default and it's not readily possible to preserve order (as you found, you can remove `players[${i}].id`, but the players are then randomly swapped around).  As mentioned below, Grails 2.3 includes many data binding enhancements, if upgrading is an option for you,